# ajax php create associative array then return sql results

Tags: php, ajax, sql-server-2008

So far I do not see how to use solutions posted from my search of "ajax php create associative array then return sql results" - need help: my submit button calls jQuery.ajax that posts select data to a PHP url; then my retriever.php file [msSQL] queries a table and returns multiple records. I want to then return the array back to my jQuery.ajax success function, and parse the returned data - and populate rows of a DataTables HTML table. here is the jQuery.ajax from caller.php:

```
jQuery('#submit').click(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
       url: "https://domain/projects/current/retrieve.php",
       //contentType: "application/json",
       data: {fy: jQuery('#fy_select').val(), lpid: jQuery('#lp_select').val(), next_year: jQuery('#fy_select').val()+1 },
       //dataType: "json",
       type: 'post',
       success: function(data, XMLHttpRequest){
        //alert(data.length);
        //alert(JSON.parse(data));
        //alert(data[0]);
        //jQuery('#activity').text("[" + JSON.parse(data)[0] + "] " + JSON.parse(data)[1]);

        jQuery.each(data, function () {
            jQuery('#activity').text("[" + JSON.parse(data)[0] + "] " + JSON.parse(data)[1]);
        });

       },
       error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
       }
    });
    return false;
});
```

pardon comments i left in my code, for if you see something i've tried that can be salvaged let me know; otherwise i hope they are not distracting. i simply need to query the db and get results, stuff them into an array and return it to ajax, then parse the activity, name from the sql result.  now the retrieve.php code. thx in advance as always!:

```
<?php

include(MSS_DB);

//get vars from jQuery .ajax post - lpid and fy:
if ($_POST['lpid'] != null && $_POST['fy'] != null ){
$lpid = $_POST['lpid'];
$fy = $_POST['fy'];
$next_year = $_POST['next_year'];

$fund_info_get = "select activityid, name from activity_table where office= " . $office . " and approveddate > '" . $fy . "-06-30' order by activityid desc";
$get_fund_result   = mssql_query($fund_info_get);
$data_array = array();
//$data_array = mssql_fetch_array($get_fund_result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_fund_result)){
    $data_array = array('activity_id' => '$row['activityid']', 'activity_name' => '$row['name']');
    //$data_array [] = $row; //tried this from another post.
}

$rowcount=mssql_num_rows($get_fund_result); //for alexander this returns 11, correct.

/*while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_fund_result)){
    $table_data[]= arrsay("id=>" = '"$row['activityid']"', "name=>" = '"$row['name']"');
}*/

//$result = "lpid/fy/next_year/get_fund_result: " . $lpid . "/" . $fy . "/" . $next_year . "/" . $fund_info_get . "";

}else{
    // either of the values doesn't exist    
    $result = "No Data Was Sent !";
}
//echo $rowcount;
//echo json_encode($table_data);
//echo $data_array;
echo json_encode($data_array);
//echo $result;
```

Comment: You should move to PDO and parameterized query's to protect against SQL injections.. Your current code is vulnerable

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` when using a MS SQL Server database will never work. I would guess PHP is chucking an error, if you haven't suppressed them. The mssql library is also discontinued, though. Switch to `sqlsrv_` if you can, or use PDO. Either way, you also need to start using parameterised queries as suggested above.

Comment: AD-you've no idea how much i've tried and all the while i had erroneous "mysql" vs "mssql" i THOUGHT i'd changed. THANK YOU! now - any kind advice before phase 2 about rendering the data in ajax success? either way, thx big time!

Comment: thx, Raymond, duly noted! i need to learn PDO then. will get to that after i get farther developing my project in test environment.

Comment: AD [somehow just saw rest of ur msg...] - tried sqlsrv_fetch_assoc but my code does not recognize that, or sqlsrv_fetch_array; and duly noted on PDO, thx!

Comment: If i was you i would try stripping everything down to just the very basic and start debugging and building as i go .. keep the very basic in your ajax as shown  jQuery.ajax({

       var test = 'Hello';

       url: "https://domain/projects/current/retrieve.php",
       data: {'test',test},
       dataType: "html",
       type: 'post',
       success: function(data){

          alert(data);

       },
       error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
       }
  });

Comment: hi Alexander, in jQuery.ajax, success... i am getting console.log(data) showing JSON data like this: [{"activity_id":11111,"activity_name":"Community Cleanup"},{"activity_id":11112,"activity_name":"Learn As You Go"}, etc. - so, in my success, how to parse through it? nothing working...

Answer (score 0):

thx, All for Your input! it helped me go forward. a brief description of my solution might help you see how each of you helped:

goal: jQuery.ajax calls someurl.php, gets mssql query data into an array, returns the json_encode array. back in jQuery.ajax success, parse through the json data. here are the operative features of each file to show the solution:

callerfile.php:

```
jQuery('#submit').click(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
       url: "https://fabrik.smartstartinc.net/ncpcphp/activity-mgmt2.0/porc_get_activities.php",
       data: {fy: jQuery('#fy_select').val(), lpid: jQuery('#lp_select').val(), next_year: jQuery('#fy_select').val()+1 },
       dataType: "json",
       type: 'post',
       success: function(data, XMLHttpRequest){

        console.log(data); //shows json: [{"activity_id":11111,"activity_name":"Community Cleanup"}, etc
        jQuery.each(data, function(index, value){
            console.log(data[index].activity_id);
            console.log(data[index].activity_name);
            //these show the id, the name.
        });

       },
       error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
       }
    });
    return false;
});
```

the PHP file that returns the json array, retrieve.php:

```
$fund_info_get = "select activityid, name from cpy_activity where lpid= " . $lpid . " and approveddate > '" . $fy . "-06-30' order by activityid desc";
$get_fund_result   = mssql_query($fund_info_get);
$data_array = array();

while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($get_fund_result)){
    $data_array[] = array('activity_id' => $row['activityid'], 'activity_name' => $row['name']);
}

}else{
    // either of the values doesn't exist    
    $result = "No Data Was Sent !";
}

echo json_encode($data_array);
```

once i used JSON.stringify and saw format of the data, i was able to start drilling into how to display it. thx again!